# change parallel observable response into sequential response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this method as legacy code that handle and execute multiple api http call and returns flattened observables and all the process is parallel because of forkJoin, and I want to change the process to sequential because of reasons, I've read some articles and most of them recommend using concatMap, but I don't actually know the right way to use concatMap in the codes, and I don't know any other way.

here's the method:

```
handleDataPost(list: Array<{ url: string, data: any }>): Observable<any> {
console.log('start data posting');
const observables: Array<Observable<any>> = [];
list.forEach(eachRequestObject => {
  observables.push(this.apiService.postData(eachRequestObject.url, JSON.stringify(eachRequestObject.data)));
});
console.log('list of observables', observables);
return forkJoin(observables);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet:

```
import {concat} from "rxjs";

...

return concat(...observables);
```

[From the docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat):

> Creates an output Observable which sequentially emits all values from given Observable and then moves on to the next.